# Error después de cambiar hostname windows 10 Home 32 bits

Tags: windows10

Tengo un equipo con windows 10 Home 32 bits. Cuando cambio el hostname con el que viene de fábrica, 11 caractéres, por uno de 14 caractéres, que no incluyen palabras reservadas del sistema, ni caractéres no permitidos, el equipo comienza a reiniciar cada 20 segundos. Ya actualizé el sistema y también ejecuté las herramientas de análisis y reparación:

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow

pero el problema continua. Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto

Comment: Complicado sin poder ver el visor de eventos. Yo intentaría ingresar y ejecutar en una terminal `shutdown -a` a ver si eso lo detiene. O si restauras/reinstalas windows desde una USB que crees con el [media creation tool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209)? (te toca en otro equipo con windows 10 32bit).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, al probar con  `shutdown -a` retorna que no es posible cancelar el apagado del sistema porque no hay una cancelación en curso. Este problema se está presetando en más de un equipo, por eso queria buscar una solución sin tener que reinstalar el SO. Agradezco sugerencias.

Comment: En teoría el hard limit de muchas aplicaciones, de NetBIOS y demás, es de 15. No debería estar asociado al cambio de hostname sino a alguna otra cosa que se instaló cuando reiniciaste para cambiar el hostname... si entras en modo a prueba de fallos, también se reinicia?

Comment: En modo a prueba de fallos no reinicia, incluso con el hostname de 14 caractéres

Comment: Entonces es un driver o una actualización de windows. Te queda determinar cuál será. Iniciar en modo seguro con funciones de red, etc... buscar cómo identificar al culpable o devolver la máquina a un punto de restauración anterior y bloquear las actualizaciones automáticas.

Comment: Entendi, ya es un camino a seguir, muchas gracias!!